# UIImagePickerController orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have my app for `iPad` whose orientation is set for `Portrait` only.

I have a form that present an `UIImagePickerController` for adding a picture from camera.

If the `iPad` can switch orientation (in `iOS settings`), then the `UIImagePickerController` allow the users to take a picture in `landscape` mode, which is fine.

The problem is that when I select the picture and come back to my app, my app is in the `landscape` mode, whereas I never authorized that in the settings of the app, and I set all my `UIViewController` to allow only `Portrait` mode.

Any idea how I can switch my app back to the right orientation ?

Pictures to understand : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8OiS9N-HRSnSVM4VEc2djE1ckE

Comment: Yes that's why I say "which is fine" :) I just need to know how to get my app back to portrait when it's dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in AppDelegate.m file,  this code help to portrait all ViewControllers:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Comment: I tried but still has the problem. I edited my post and added screenshots to show you.

Comment: I try this and I can not reproduce the same problem, but if you still has problem one hack way is to set your project orientation Portrait in Targets, delete derived data of app then again run app hope will solve your problem!